# Simple DOM mutation abstraction

Tags: javascript, dom

Background: I need to use mutation observers to watch for nodes being added/removed under a specific element.

The code below is an attempt to implement something re-usable that uses [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver)s where available and falls back to [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) where not available, providing a simple unified interface to both. The aim is to have the behaviour as predictable as possible regardless if the mechanism that is powering it behind.

You will notice it only implements a very part of the functionality that is available through these methods, but that is intentional, as it only implements the parts I need to use. I may look to extend it in the future.

```
/*jslint plusplus: true, white: true, browser: true */

/*
 * DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory definition
 */
function DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory() {'use strict';}

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MOFactory = {
  isSupported: function() {
    // Determines whether the environment supports MutationObservers and caches a
    // reference to the constructor if it does
    'use strict';
    if (this.MOConstructor === undefined) {
      this.MOConstructor = null;
      if (window.MutationObserver !== undefined) { // Mozilla/standard
        this.MOConstructor = window.MutationObserver;
      } else if (window.WebKitMutationObserver !== undefined) { // Webkit
        this.MOConstructor = window.WebKitMutationObserver;
      }
    }
    return this.MOConstructor !== null;
  },
  getObserver: function(callback) {
    // Gets a MutationObserver instance
    'use strict';
    return new this.MOConstructor(callback);
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.getListener = function(element) {
  // Determines which wrapper constructor to use, caches the result and gets an instance
  'use strict';
  if (this.WrapperInUse === undefined) {
    DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.WrapperInUse = null;
    if (this.MOFactory.isSupported()) {
      DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.WrapperInUse = this.MutationObserverWrapper;
    } else if (window.addEventListener) {
      DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.WrapperInUse = this.MutationEventWrapper;
    }
  }
  if (this.WrapperInUse === null) {
    throw new Error('Your browser does not support Child List mutation listeners');
  }
  return new this.WrapperInUse(this, element);
};

/*
 * MutationObserverWrapper definition
 */
DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper = function(parent, element) {
  // Constructor for MutationObserver wrapper
  'use strict';
  this.parent = parent;
  this.element = element;
  this.callbacks = {
    nodeadded: [],
    noderemoved: []
  };
  this.mutationObserver = parent.MOFactory.getObserver(this.observerCallback.bind(this));
};

// Whether the observer is currently active (boolean flag)
DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.observing = false;

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.observerCallback = function(mutations) {
  // Iterate over all nodes in mutation and fire event callbacks
  'use strict';
  var i, j, k, l, m, n;
  for (i = 0, l = mutations.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (j = 0, m = mutations[i].removedNodes.length; j < m; j++) {
      for (k = 0, n = this.callbacks.noderemoved.length; k < n; k++) {
        this.callbacks.noderemoved[k](mutations[i].removedNodes[j]);
      }
    }
    for (j = 0, m = mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j < m; j++) {
      for (k = 0, n = this.callbacks.nodeadded.length; k < n; k++) {
        this.callbacks.nodeadded[k](mutations[i].addedNodes[j]);
      }
    }
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.on = function(eventName, callback) {
  // Register an event callback and start the observer if required
  'use strict';
  eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
  if (this.callbacks[eventName] !== undefined && typeof callback === 'function' && this.callbacks[eventName].indexOf(callback) < 0) {
    this.callbacks[eventName].push(callback);
    if (!this.observing) {
      this.mutationObserver.observe(this.element, { childList: true, subtree: true });
      this.observing = true;
    }
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.off = function(eventName, callback) {
  // De-register an event callback and stop the observer if no callbacks left
  'use strict';
  var i;
  eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
  if (this.callbacks[eventName] !== undefined) {
    i = this.callbacks[eventName].indexOf(callback);
    if (i > -1) {
      this.callbacks[eventName].splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  if (this.observing && !this.callbacks.nodeadded.length && !this.callbacks.noderemoved.length) {
    this.mutationObserver.disconnect();
    this.observing = false;
  }
};

/*
 * MutationEventWrapper definition
 */
DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationEventWrapper = function(parent, element) {
  // Constructor for Mutation Events wrapper
  'use strict';
  this.parent = parent;
  this.element = element;
  this.callbacks = {
    nodeadded: [],
    noderemoved: []
  };
};

// Whether the observer is currently active (boolean flag)
DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.insertObserving = false;
DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationObserverWrapper.prototype.removeObserving = false;

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationEventWrapper.prototype.nodeInsertedListener = function(event) {
  // Fire insert callbacks
  'use strict';
  var i, l, node = event.target || event.srcElement;
  for (i = 0, l = this.callbacks.nodeadded.length; i < l; i++) {
    this.callbacks.nodeadded[i](node);
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationEventWrapper.prototype.nodeRemovedListener = function(event) {
  // Fire remove callbacks
  'use strict';
  var i, l, node = event.target || event.srcElement;
  for (i = 0, l = this.callbacks.noderemoved.length; i < l; i++) {
    this.callbacks.noderemoved[i](node);
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationEventWrapper.prototype.on = function(eventName, callback) {
  // Register an event callback and add the event listeners if required
  'use strict';
  eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
  if (this.callbacks[eventName] !== undefined && typeof callback === 'function' && this.callbacks[eventName].indexOf(callback) < 0) {
    this.callbacks[eventName].push(callback);
    if (!this.insertObserving && this.callbacks.nodeadded.length) {
      this.nodeInsertedListener = this.nodeInsertedListener.bind(this);
      this.element.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', this.nodeInsertedListener);
      this.insertObserving = true;
    }
    if (!this.removeObserving && this.callbacks.noderemoved.length) {
      this.nodeRemovedListener = this.nodeRemovedListener.bind(this);
      this.element.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', this.nodeRemovedListener);
      this.removeObserving = true;
    }
  }
};

DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype.MutationEventWrapper.prototype.off = function(eventName, callback) {
  // De-register an event callback and remove the event listeners if no callbacks left
  'use strict';
  var i;
  eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
  if (this.callbacks[eventName] !== undefined) {
    i = this.callbacks[eventName].indexOf(callback);
    if (i > -1) {
      this.callbacks[eventName].splice(i, 1);
    }
    if (this.insertObserving && !this.callbacks.nodeadded.length) {
      this.element.removeEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', this.nodeInsertedListener);
      this.insertObserving = false;
    }
    if (this.removeObserving && !this.callbacks.noderemoved.length) {
      this.element.removeEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', this.nodeRemovedListener);
      this.removeObserving = false;
    }
  }
};


/*
 * Example Usage
 */
var factory = new DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory();
var listener = factory.getListener(document.getElementById('some-element'));
listener.on('NodeAdded', function(addedNode) {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Any reason you're not declaring `'use strict'` globally?

Comment: Those functions are quite a mouth-full

Comment: JS !== Java. Factories?! Come on...

Comment: @JosephSilber Because JSLint complains about it, that's the sole reason.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I would be quite happy to use an alternative approach, but I have yet to understand why this is such a problem. The above code works, does not continually redeclare methods because everything is done on the prototype, and because it's a factory I can avoid tight coupling. I am open to other approaches (that's why I posted the question) but can you explain the better approach and *why* it is better?

Comment: @Zirak Indeed they are but a) they are accurate descriptions of what they do and b) one of the places this code will be used is in the environment of a Firefox extension, where all extensions (ridiculously, as far as I can work out from the docs) share a namespace. As a result I try to name my global objects in a way that minimises collision risk.

Answer (score 2):

2 observations:

1. You can place 'use strict' in an IIFE, which keeps lint happy and it's DRYer

   ```
   function DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory() {'use strict';}

   (function () 
   {
     'use strict';
      /* Do your thing with DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype,
          no need to repeat 'use strict */
   }();
   ```
2. You can assign all functions to a prototype with Object Literal Notation like you do for `MOFactory`. So you do not need to repeat over a dozen times 
   `DOMChildListMutationListenerFactory.prototype`.